# Django: get current URL path to use in a form

Tags: python, django

I have been stuck on this for a while now. I need to extract the current domain name of the tenant in order to use as a parameter to upload data in this tenant schema.

I am struggling to make this work because of the structure of my view. This is what I have been able to do so far

forms.py

```
class ETL(forms.Form):
    Historical = forms.FileField()
    Pre_processing = forms.FileField()
    Supplier = forms.FileField()
    parameters = forms.FileField()


    def process_data(self, request ,*args, **kwargs):

        url = request.get_full_path()
        print(url)

        dbschema = remove_www(request.get_host().split(':')[0]).lower()
        print(url)




        fh = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['Historical'].file)
        fpp = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['Pre_processing'].file)
        fs = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['Supplier'].file)
        fp = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['parameters'].file)

 ........
```

and my view.py

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class Getfiles(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):
    template_name = 'upload.html'
    form_class = ETL
    success_url = 'Home'



    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.process_data()
        print('data_processed well')

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

with this view format, I am struggling on how to pass the request.get_hosts() inside of the view. How can I can fix it?

Is this a proper way to get the schema name or is there a better way to get the tenant schema in the form?

UPDATE:

I have been able to modify my view, no error and it redirect to the right page  but it does not process my data.

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class Getfiles(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):
    template_name = 'upload.html'
    form_class = ETL
    success_url = 'Home'

    def gooView(request, form):
        if form.is_valid():
            url = request.get_full_path()
            form.process_data()

                #redirect = 'Home'
                #return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect)
            return super().form_valid(form)

        else:
            form = ETL()

        context = {
            'form': form
        }

        return render(request, 'upload.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to pass the `request.get_hosts()`, you should have access to the `request` variable. They only possible way that I can find is for a class-based view to use it through the `self` object. For example, `self.request.get_hosts()`.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/

I hope that helps!

Comment: in the view or in my form. or in both? my issue I don't see how i can do this without modifying the behavior of the current code that I have

Comment: in the view, where you handle the business logic

Comment: so it is possible to achieve the same output with a 'regular' view, without have to use that FormView? because of the FormView I cannot pass in the request argument

Comment: Thank you! If you accept it too, I would really appreciate it! Nice to help you.

Comment: hey man here is some update I updated my post because it still not doing the trick

Comment: Yes because you do no not create a `form_valid()` function inside the class. The `gooView` should be renamed to `form_valid()`. I suggest you to post a new question with your new issue, so that I can give you a proper answer, with a sample code that will possibly solve it. Also, link question so that I can find it.

Comment: Ok thank you, here is the link to the new post I have made https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61331276/django-error-with-form-valid-and-get-full-path