# Django : error with form_valid and get_full_path()

Tags: python, django

I am trying to acquire the current tenant's domain name through a form. I am trouble with writing the view that would achieve that.

here is my form.py:

```
class ETL(forms.Form):
    Historical = forms.FileField()
    Pre_processing = forms.FileField()
    Supplier = forms.FileField()
    parameters = forms.FileField()


    def process_data(self, *args, **kwargs):

        url = self.request.get_full_path()

        dbschema = remove_www(url.split(':')[0]).lower()
        engine = create_engine('postgresql://pierre:56-Pmtmpmtm@127.0.0.1:5432/dbexostock12',
                               connect_args={'options': '-csearch_path={}'.format(dbschema)})

        fh = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['Historical'].file)
        fpp = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['Pre_processing'].file)
        fs = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['Supplier'].file)
        fp = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['parameters'].file)

        ....
```

view.py

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class Getfiles(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):
    template_name = 'upload.html'
    form_class = ETL
    success_url = 'Home'

    def form_valid(request, form):
        url = request.get_full_path()
        form.process_data()

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

and here is the error that I get:

```
AttributeError at /upload.html
'Getfiles' object has no attribute 'get_full_path'
```

I am beginner with django, I am not sure how to resolve this, and the documentation about it got me a bit confused, especially about the form_valid() method. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_valid` has no `request` as first parameter. The parameters are `self` and `form`. You can access the request object with `self.request`:

```
class GetfilesView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'upload.html'
    form_class = ETL
    success_url = 'Home'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        url = self.request.get_full_path()
        form.process_data()

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Note that your *form* has no `request` either. You can pass data, for example through the method parameters:

```
class GetfilesView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'upload.html'
    form_class = ETL
    success_url = 'Home'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        url = self.request.get_full_path()
        form.process_data(url)

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

and in the form:

```
class ETL(forms.Form):
    Historical = forms.FileField()
    Pre_processing = forms.FileField()
    Supplier = forms.FileField()
    parameters = forms.FileField()

    def process_data(self, url):
        dbschema = remove_www(url.split(':')[0]).lower()
        engine = create_engine('postgresql://pierre:56-Pmtmpmtm@127.0.0.1:5432/dbexostock12',
                               connect_args={'options': '-csearch_path={}'.format(dbschema)})

        fh = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['Historical'].file)
        fpp = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['Pre_processing'].file)
        fs = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['Supplier'].file)
        fp = io.TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data['parameters'].file)
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much, I guess I have still have to understand how forms and views interact. but thanks a lot

Comment: hey this is a bit of a long shot you have already helped so much Willem, but I noticed that this return /upload as the url path, would there be a way to get everything like http://www.tenant.mysite.com:8000/upload ?

Comment: @Anastasia: to the best of my knowledge, you can not easily do that. The idea is that you can run the same Django server on multiple domains. So by starting with a slash, the same domain is used. In the password reset email for example (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html#L6), it is written as `{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}` so the domain is not part of what is returned by `{% url ... %}`.

Comment: I found out by replacing '''get_full_path()'''by '''get_absolute_uri()''' and then a little trick with parsing the url to output the tenant part did the trick. Thank you for your kind help